Countable and uncountable sets of Kraus operators for channels
Given two seperable Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_{A/B}$ and algebras $\mathcal{M}_{A/B}\subseteq B(\mathcal{H}_{A/B})$, a linear map $\Phi$  between the sets of trace class operators $T(\mathcal{H}_{A/B})$ (or its dual $\Phi^*$ between the algebras) is a quantum channel if it is unital (TP) and completely positive (CP). A standard result, Kraus' theorem shown here, tells us that
$$\Phi(b)=\sum_iK_ibK_i^\dagger$$
where $K_i$ are bounded linear operators called Kraus operators and $\sum_i K_i^\dagger K_i=1$ converges strongly. This is very familiar to an quantum info researcher, however it does not seem that natural when coming from a QFT/optics perspective. Let $k(\gamma,\lambda)=g(\gamma,\lambda)^{1/2}$ be the squareroot of the Gaussian with mean $\lambda$. Then a Gaussian measurement of a (possibily unbounded) self adjoint operator $A$ is defined as $K_\gamma=k(\gamma, A)$ defined in the spectral sense, so that
$$\Phi_A(b)=\int_\mathbb{R} d\gamma K_\gamma bK^\dagger_\gamma$$
is a Gaussian measurment of $A$. This certainly defines a channel (unital is obvious and CP follows from the fact that $K_\gamma$ are self-adjoint) and so should have a decomposition in terms of a countable set of Kraus operators. As an example, this appears in QFT where $A=\phi(f)$ is an unbounded operator with $\sigma(A)=\mathbb{R}$. While it is common to be able to find a large number of Kraus decomposotions, possibly with different numbers of Kraus operators, I fail to see how this channel can have a countable decomposition for generic $A$, let alone what form it would take.


and so should have a decomposition in terms of a countable set of Kraus operators

if $H$ is separable and $\Phi$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous. Which is not surprising since $\sigma$-weakly continuous things on a separable space are inherently countable.
It is not clear to me that your map is $\sigma$-weakly continuous.
